# converting regular expression from BBdit to php

Tags: regex

i'm using bbedit to 'test' the extraction of some data from a web page using regular expression.

This works well in bbedit however i'd like to use cUrl to download the page itself and then use php to perform the matching/extraction, instead of bbedit.

unfortunately though i don't know much about php libraries. which one is easier to learn/use for this?

Comment: i have zero knowledge in php, but googling `regex php` will help not less than stackoverflow, but in less time.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead of regex its very useful for extracting information from HTML pages ....

And for cURL, the [documentation is also very good](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php)

Comment: didn't know about DOMDocument, seems interesting although a bit complicated. Will have a look at that - however it will really depend on the tag inside the file i have to parse, which contains a lot of class selectors and very few IDs..

Comment: @Patrick you can use [XPath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) for help with that